# Add new animation on transition end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a script to make content boxes slide from the top upon entry and then slides down upon exit.

It's almost working perfectly however, when you click on the button for content box one, then content box two, then back to one again, one comes in from the bottom instead of the top.

I think I understand why this is happening (because the code runs all in one hit, and thus instead of going from below the viewport, to above the viewport and then into view, it just goes from below into view)  but can't figure out how to make it always come in from the top.

HTML:

```
<div class="slidey slidey1 enter">
    Content Box 1
</div>
<div class="slidey slidey2">
    Content Box 1
</div>
<div class="slidey slidey3">
    Content Box 1
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slidey { top:-100% }
.enter { top:0; transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; }
.exit { top:100%; transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; }
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".changer").click(function(){
    if ($(".slidey" + $(this).data("slidey")).hasClass("enter")) {
        return false
    }  else {
        $(".slidey").removeClass("exit");
        $(".slidey.enter").addClass("exit").removeClass("enter");
        $(".slidey" + $(this).data("slidey")).addClass("enter");
        $(".changer").removeClass("link_change");
        $(".changer" + $(this).data("slidey")).addClass("link_change");
        return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The page is no longer available to be viewed.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong, probably a simplification typo. You need `slidey1, slidey2, slidey3` instead you have two `slidey3`... try always to add all the minimal (and valid) code that recreates your problem - so one does not need to rebuild it all from scratch or by visiting your website. ;)

Comment: will bare this in mind for next time @RokoC.Buljan - by all the code that recreates the problem do you mean the bare minimum you would need to stick it in jsfiddle for example and have it run? (so in the above i would need to include the links as well?)

Comment: the code editor allows you to paste in Snippets of code `[<>]` (Snippet Button). You don't have to crate jsfiddle not jsbin nor codepens etc. I mean, if you want to get a reliable (not vague) and precise answer you'll do your best. Otherwise you can only expect general answers, cause people in hurry will certainly not go to your website, inspect elements and loose valuable time. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding a class your should assign a `"transitionend"` listener like i.e:

```
$(".myElement").addClass("transitionClass").on("transitionend", function() {
    // Transition ended.
    // Do more stuff.
});
```

I recreated and simplified your HTML, CSS to create this example, so you might want to ignore that part, but focus on the jQ code. Should work even on your page out of the box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var $slides = $(".slidey");
  
  $(".changer").click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault(); // Instead of return false;
    var num = $(this).data("slidey");
    var $target = $(".slidey"+ num);
    
    $(".enter").not($target) // (not the already active one)
      .removeClass("enter")  // remove unwanted classes
      .addClass("exit")      // make it go to bottom
      .on("transitionend", function(){ // snap it back to -100% top...
              $(this).removeClass("exit"); // by removing the exit class.
      });

    $target.addClass("enter"); // Animate current down into view
    
    // UL links
    $(".changer").removeClass("link_change");
    $(this).addClass("link_change");

  });
  
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
html, body{height:100%;}
body{overflow:hidden;}

#navbar{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:130px;
  right:130px;
}
#navbar ul {list-style:none;}

.link_change{
  color:fuchsia;
}

.slidey {
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
  height:90vh;
  background:#ddd;
  top:-100%;
}
.enter {
  top:0;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.exit {
  top:100%;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul id="navlinks">
    <li class="changer changer1 link_change" data-slidey="1">home</li>
    <li class="changer changer2" data-slidey="2">profile</li>
    <li class="changer changer3" data-slidey="3">message</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="slidey slidey1 enter">Content Box 1</div>
<div class="slidey slidey2">Content Box 2</div>
<div class="slidey slidey3">Content Box 3</div>
```

Comment: You should probably make sure the 'transition' handler runs only once to be kosher